# Rails: update table cell without refresh by using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Index.html.erb has one form and one table
I use Ajax make the form submit without redirect

```
<%= form_for approval,remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :pass %>
  <%= f.submit%>
<% end %>
```

But I also want the table could update as soon as I submit the from below without refresh.

```
<% @approval.each do |approval| %>
<td><%= approval.progress %></td>
<% end %>
```

Controller

```
class ApprovalController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @approval = Approval.where(user_id: id)
    end

    def update
       @approval.update_attributes(app_params)
       redirect_to approvals_path
    end 
end
```

How to reach this goal ?

Comment: Could you send the ajax request and on the success handler update the dom accordingly? Would that be a solution?

Comment: @DiegoGallegos I  am not sure how to do that, not familar with Ajax

Answer (score 0):

Create a `create.js` and append the table data `<td>` to the table using `create.js`

**approvals_controller.rb**

```
class ApprovalController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @approval = Approval.new(params[:approval])
    @approval.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

**create.js.erb**

```
<% if @approval.valid? %>
  $('#wrapper').append("<td><%= @approval.progress %></td>")
<% end %>
```

**NOTE:** `#wrapper` is the wrapper around your loop

Comment: What if I do not want do create something, just want to update something? Create update.js.erb ?

Comment: yes, but in that case, you will need to either replace existing row content

Comment: and you will also need to add `id` to your rows to identify them for replacement

Answer (score 0):

First you would have to serialize your form. Then you with the serialize data you can do something like this:

```
var data = $('#form-id').serialize(); // example, this can vary depending on the complexity of the form

$.post(url, data ,function(response){
/* Here you would check the response from your server. You can send a string 
 such as 'SUCCESS' or 'FAILED' */
    if(response){
        /* update dom, you can use the selector of the dom element */
        $(HERE CLASS OR ID).text(data.valueToUpdate) // $('#id') or $('.id')
    }
});
```

This is an easy alternative to do it.